# How to make jquery animate work fluently?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have this code inside my html page.

```
  $('#buttonMenu').on('click',function(){
    var errDiv = $("#divWhichToMoveTo");
    errDiv.show();
    var pos = errDiv.position().top;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: pos });
  });


  <li><a id="buttonMenu" title="Yea" alt="Yea" href="#">Yea</a></li>

  <div id="divWhichToMoveTo"><strong>An error occured, oh noes!!</strong></div>
```

It is supposed to make the page scroll down (gently) to the point where is the "divWhichToMoveTo" when the user hit the "buttonMenu". It works, but i have several button and several div within a long page. Sometimes passing from one to another in differente points of the html page, i can see, for a millisecond,  the beginning of the html page before the animation starts and bring me from the point where i am to the point where i want to land. I'm missing something?

Comment: I think I can help to clarify the issue that the other answerers seem to have missed. Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/fpxuC/255/ scroll down to the "Yea" link, and pay attention to the right scrollbar as you click it. The scrollbar JUMPS to the top, *then* animates to the end. Elisabetta is asking why the page jumps to the top before scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$('#buttonMenu').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var errDiv = $("#divWhichToMoveTo");
    errDiv.show(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: errDiv.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action which is to go to `#`. This was the cause of  the page jumping.

`.position().top` was returning the wrong value. This uses `.offset()` which gets the offset relative to the document and works perfectly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cEwQv/1/ (margin just applied so there was somewhere to scroll to)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for the full explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

Adding javascript:void(0) in place of # in anchor links will also help

For Example

write

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Yea</a>
```

in place of

```
<a href="#">Yea</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the time in milliseconds like this -->

```
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: pos }, 2000)
```

1000 milliseconds is taken as 1 second if I remember correctly!